# Tomcat8 WebSockets (JSR-356) with Guice 3.0

Tags: java, websocket, guice, tomcat8, jsr356

I am trying to @Inject a Guice service into a @ServerEndpoint. I am using Tomcat 8.0.15 as the JSR-356 implementation. However, the dependency injection isn't working. Is there any additional configuration that needs to be done in order to enable Guice injection? Note that I am using all standard javax annotations only.

Comment: "the dependency injection isn't working" ... can you describe that in more detail?

Comment: I get an instantiation exception when I try to do a constructor injection using @Inject inside the SeverEndpoint.

Answer (score 8):

I figured this out. The Websocket endpoint needs to have a custom configurator, which creates and returns instances using the Guice injector instance.

Example:

Custom Guice servlet context listener:

```
public class CustomServletContextListener extends GuiceServletContextListener { 
    public static Injector injector;

    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        injector = Guice.createInjector(...);
        return injector;
    }
}
```

Websockets custom configurator:

```
public class CustomConfigurator extends Configurator {
  @Override
  public <T> T getEndpointInstance(Class<T> clazz)
        throws InstantiationException {
    return CustomServletContextListener.injector.getInstance(clazz);
  }
}
```

And then in the Websocket endpoint:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/ws/sample_endpoint", configurator = CustomConfigurator.class)
public class SampleEndpoint {
  private final SomeService service;

  @Inject
  public SampleEndpoint(SomeService service) {
    this.service = service;
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: it is much safer to use field/setter injections and do `super.getEndpointInstance(endpointClass)` and then `injector.injectMembers(endpointInstance)`. That's because `super` may return some container-specific decorator wrapping the newly created instance of `endpointClass`. Furthermore the spec requires Endpoint classes to have a paramless constructor, so some containers may refuse to deploy the above `SampleEndpoint` at all... 
...and of course storing anything on static vars is just asking for trouble in sooo many ways ;-]

Answer (score 6):

Building upon Aritra's own answer:

To be honest, I don't know for sure if this works with Guice 3.0, but it does work for 4.0, which is the current stable release.

I think a somewhat cleaner approach is to change your CustomConfigurator into something like this:

```
public class CustomConfigurator extends Configurator {
    @Inject
    private static Injector injector;

    public <T> T getEndpointInstance(Class<T> endpointClass) {
        return injector.getInstance(endpointClass);
    }
}
```

And then from your extended `ServletModule` class' `configureServlets` method, call `requestStaticInjection(CustomConfigurator.class)`

That way you won't expose the injector to everyone. I don't know about you, but it gives me a nice and fuzzy feeling inside to know that no one will be able to mess with my injector :-).

Comment: this answer has exactly the same issues as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499800/tomcat8-websockets-jsr-356-with-guice-3-0#comment135633934_28031697

Answer (score 0):

First, using annotations to do any "magic" behind the scene is a bad idea in general: it's much better to deploy `Endpoints` programmatically in `ServletContextListener.contextInitialized(event)` with `ServerContainer.addEndpoint(config)`, so that you have the full control and **can avoid storing injector on static vars**.

Now regarding the injection, the solution is to define your custom `ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator` as stated in other answers already, however it is much safer to use field/setter injections in `Endpoint` classes and call `super.getEndpointInstance(endpointClass)` followed by `injector.injectMembers(endpointInstance)`. That's because `super` (default `Configurator` impl of the given container) may return instances of container-specific dynamic subclasses or decorators wrapping the newly created instance of `endpointClass`. Furthermore, the spec requires `Endpoint` classes to have a paramless constructor, so some containers may refuse to deploy `Endpoint` classes that use constructor params for injections.

```java
public class MyConfigurator extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator {

    public <EndpointT> EndpointT getEndpointInstance(Class<EndpointT> endpointClass)
            throws InstantiationException {
        EndpointT endpointInstance = super.getEndpointInstance(endpointClass);
        injector.injectMembers(endpointInstance);
        return endpointInstance;
    }
}
```

Now a `SevletContextListener` that adds `Endpoints` programmatically:

```java
public class MyServletCtxListener implements SevletContextListener {

    ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator endpointConfigurator;
    ServerContainer endpointContainer;

    void addEndpoint(Class<?> endpointClass, String path) throws DeploymentException {
        endpointContainer.addEndpoint(
            ServerEndpointConfig.Builder
                .create(endpointClass, path)
                .configurator(endpointConfigurator)
                .build()
        );
    }

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent initialization) {
        final var ctx = initialization.getServletContext();
        endpointContainer = (ServerContainer)
                ctx.getAttribute("javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer");
        final var injector = Guice.createInjector(
            // put modules here...
        );
        endpointConfigurator = new MyConfigurator(injector); // NO STATIC :)

        try {
            addEndpoint(MyEndpoint.class, "/websocket/my");
            addEndpoint(MyOtherEndpoint.class, "/websocket/myOther");
            addEndpoint(MyYetAnotherEndpoint.class, "/websocket/myYetAnother");
            // ...
        } catch (DeploymentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);  // fail fast
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if you go for programmatic adding, your `Endpoint` classes should be extending `javax.websocket.Endpoint` / `jakarta.websocket.Endpoint` according to the spec (although AFAIR Tomcat specifically used to be relaxed regarding this requirement).

Some related self-promotion: for anyone combining guice with websockets, you may find useful my lib that provides custom `Scopes` for ws `Endpoints`: https://github.com/morgwai/servlet-scopes